# Jquery toggle close other containers

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Jquery toggle method to display divs based on a link that the user will click.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9tg/905/

The only thing I want to change is to have the other menus close when a different one is clicked. So only 1 menu will ever be open at one time. Can someone show me the most straight forward method to achieve this?

```
Jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#homeMenu').click(function() {
            $('#menu1').slideToggle("fast");
    });
        $('#shopMenu').click(function() {
            $('#menu2').slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $('#faqMenu').click(function() {
            $('#menu3').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="Navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="homeMenu">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="shopMenu">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="faqMenu">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="menu1" style="display:none;">This is menu one</div>
<div id="menu2" style="display:none;">This is menu two</div>
<div id="menu3" style="display:none;">This is menu three</div>
```

Comment: You want only 1 expanded at a time ?

Comment: Yes. im sorry. i will edit post to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to place your divs in a container:

```
<div>
  <div id="menu1" style="display:none;">This is menu one</div>
  <div id="menu2" style="display:none;">This is menu two</div>
  <div id="menu3" style="display:none;">This is menu three</div>
</div>
```

And then alter your JavaScript for each menu item like so:

```
$('#menu1').slideToggle("fast").siblings().hide();
```

Comment: Wow. I love this solution. will upvote when possible.

Comment: Consider a solution that doesn't rely upon multiple IDs instead. That can get difficult to maintain and is somewhat fragile in that it depends on a lot of markup.

Answer (score 2):

It's rarely a good idea to use a bunch of IDs for this type of thing. Instead, use DOM traversal relative to the clicked element:

```
$('#navigation ul li').click(function () {
    var idx = $(this).index();

    $('#content > div').eq(idx).slideToggle().siblings().slideUp();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4xy5ghkn/)

Note that I did put a wrapper around the content. This solution depends on just two IDs, and that could be reduced to one with some additional markup changes.

Comment: While this is a great answer someone got there before you. Thanks for the insight though! I like the .slideup() better than the .hide()

Comment: Timing doesn't matter when the answers are rather different. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can slideUp manually the other containers.

```
 var menus = ['#menu1', '#menu2', '#menu3']

    $('#homeMenu').click(function() {
            $('#menu1').slideToggle("fast");
            $(menus.join(',').replace('#menu1')).slideUp();
    });
        $('#shopMenu').click(function() {
            $('#menu2').slideToggle("fast");
            $(menus.join(',').replace('#menu2')).slideUp();

    });
    $('#faqMenu').click(function() {
            $('#menu3').slideToggle("fast");
                          $(menus.join(',').replace('#menu3')).slideUp();

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9tg/906/

Comment: While this works, it's needlessly complex and somewhat difficult to read. Only more experienced developers will know what `join` is doing there.

Comment: @isherwood yeah i know, i upvoted bristol james answer